# Assets path with SDL2 library

Tags: c++, path, sdl, assets, sdl-image

I'm trying to load image with IMG_Load() function from SDL.
I saw from tutorials that they doesn't need full path for asset files.

But when I try to do that, it doesn't work.

My solution is include full path of those files, but I found that is clunky. Especially when I try to collaborate with my friend, it's hard to synchronize source files since we use different file paths.

May I ask what is typical way to collaborate between programmers when they have different setup, different file paths? I think that I need to simplify the file path for asset.

I tried to add include directories for compiler, but it only work with header files, not for asset files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the *current working directory*. On Windows, when starting a program from the exporer with a double-click, it matches the location of the .exe, but this isn't always the case, e.g. when running from some IDEs.

Use `SDL_GetBasePath()` to get the directory where the .exe is located. Prepend it to your asset paths.

Comment: Thank you so much. With your provided function, now I know why it didn't work. Since I'm using CLion with CMake, the "current working directory" is within cmake-build-debug folder. When I move my image to that folder, it works as expected. Anyway, thank you so much.